# magento 1.9.0.1 email notification not working

Tags: email, magento, notifications

I have a pretty weird problem. When I get an order, the order mail is sent. Also all mails relating to the customer account are sent.
However, all notifications of status changes are not sent automatically, even though it is enabled accordingly in System->Configuration->Sales->Sales E-Mails (Set to Yes).

When I check the orders, even completed ones, I get the the note "Customer not informed".

If I let an order go through manually and check the box to send a notification, this notification gets through perfectly.

So the issue is really only the follow up e-mails with status changes. Do you have any idea?

Magento 1.9.0.1

Comment: How are the order status changes happening, through soap api calls? Any third party extension?

Comment: Its through a third party extension, developed from the fulfillment company. I think, the problem should not be the extension, if I change the status manually, then it should work. But it doesen't.